# How to configure server side parameters in tableau desktop (with HIVE)?

Tags: hive, tableau-api

I am trying to connect tableau desktop to Hadoop Hive connection. I want to change the default hive engine to TEZ . How can i change this parameter through tableau desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing which I have figured it out is, you can use :

`initial SQL`

option to set default engine  to TEZ. However problem with this is, it only gets fired when firing first tableau query, for subsequent queries again engine related changes are reverted back.I am in research on this with Tableau, and will post once I hear anything concrete.

Comment: Yes. it is true :(. You can play with adding the Advanced configuration into ODBC driver. I was tried to do this and it works but Tableau is getting extremely slow. Still not find the correct solution